# MS SQL 2008R2 Peer-to-Peer replication Zombie data

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-replication, sql-server-2016

We have two SQL 2008R2 boxes - each in a geographically separate data center - that stay sync'd using peer to peer replication (with a pair of smaller boxes acting as replication providers).  This replication has been running like a champ for more than 3 years with no major issues.  Recently we brought up a 2016 (with its own rep provider) box in a third data center with the ultimate goal that one of the 2008R2 data centers will go away.  2008R2-1 is still peer to peer with only 2008R2-2.  As I understand it, 2008R2-2 has one peer-to-peer topology setup with -1 and another topology setup with 2016-1.

Now for the weird part.  One table had normal user type updates occur between 13:52 and 13:55 on 9July2019.  Then more updates happened on these same records. Any changes to this table fire an audit trigger that records the original data, changed data, user, time, etc. Sometime between 14:40 and 14:50 on 11July2019 some data items reverted to the 9July changes.  An example of what the audit may look like:
2019-07-09 13:55 DueDate changed from 2019-07-11T12:00 to 2019-07-11T17:00
2019-07-09 15:30 DueDate changed from 2019-07-11T17:00 to 2019-07-13T17:00
2019-07-10 10:30 DueDate changed from 2019-07-13T17:00 to 2019-07-15T17:00
2019-07-10 14:30 DueDate changed from 2019-07-15T17:00 to 2019-07-16T17:00
2019-07-11 14:51 DueDate changed from 2019-07-11T12:00 to 2019-07-13T17:00

No audit record of the data being changed back, just an audit record of the data being fixed. Any ideas on how this could possibly happen would be greatly helpful